# How to refresh arguments after exception with @Retryable?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception, spring-retry

I have the following code:

```
@Retryable(value = ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException.class, maxAttempts = 10, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 50L))
public void foo(Request request, String status) {
    request.setStatus();
    // some additional logic
    repository.save(request);
}
```

Method `foo` is called from many places. However, I need to refresh `request` from DB every time exception is happened. How can I configure annotation to refresh argument of the method?

Comment: By refresh you mean alter the request object?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to add custom logic for every retry is to register a **RetryTemplate**

```java
    @Bean
    public RetryTemplate retryTemplate() {
        RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
        
        FixedBackOffPolicy fixedBackOffPolicy = new FixedBackOffPolicy();
        fixedBackOffPolicy.setBackOffPeriod(2000l);
        retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(fixedBackOffPolicy);

        SimpleRetryPolicy retryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy();
        retryPolicy.setMaxAttempts(2);
        retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);
        //add policy for wanted exception
        
        return retryTemplate;
    }
```

and to use this

```
public void foo(Request request, String status) {
    retryTemplate.execute(t -> {
         request.setStatus();
         // some additional logic
         repository.save(request);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to write @Retryable annotation like this

```
@Retryable(value = { RetryException.class }, maxAttempts = 4, label="retry API", backoff = @Backoff(delay = 5000))
```